# Stop httpModules execution for css, images and other request

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, iis-7.5, httpmodule

I am new to programming world Please help me .

I want to stop execution of http modules for css images and javascripts how can i achive it

please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `<system.webServer>` use `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">`.